# URL Rewrite - Remove .html extension

Tags: .net, html, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

So the idea is to remove the .html extension from each page like so...

```
www.website.com/File.html > www.website.com/File
www.website.com/Folder/File.html > www.website.com/Folder/File
```

Now I've managed to do this using a URL Rewrite, but it means having to write a rewrite for each page, which is time consuming, not efficient and impractical say if the website is more than 20 pages.

Is there a way to do this by writing just one or two rewrites in the web.config?

Comment: I would also like to know!!! Help SO users UNITE!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solution worked for me in the end:

```
<rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)\.(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.(.*)" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Nice one Ryano! I would vote you up - but we have been told off about voting up in the past...

Comment: Unfortunately, this also removes .css, .js, and other extensions

Answer (score 1):

Adding the answer from [Remove HTML extension with web config permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631493/remove-html-extension-with-web-config-permanently/35523747) here. This worked very nicely for me, using the URL Rewrite 2.1 module. You edit this into the applicationHost.config file.
Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1821692/feeeper

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Hide .html ext">
            <match ignoreCase="true" url="^(.*)"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html" matchType="IsFile"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.html"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirecting .html ext" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*).html"/>
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).html"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Improved my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62501711/12508260

Answer (score 0):

Use the rewrite module for IIS 7.x:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/webmaster/url-rewriting-with-iiss-url-rewrite-module/710

Although I have tried this, I've never gotten the actual rule set to do it automatically **without** having a rule **per** page name.

+1 to anyone who can shed light on this!