# Remove HTML extension with web config permanently

Tags: html, iis, redirect, web-config

I am trying to remove html extension from pages using web.config. Below is the code i am using in web.config  file

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="rewrite html">
      <match url="(.*)$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" negate="true" pattern="(.*).html" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.html" />
    </rule> 
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

it is working fine and removing html extension, however there seems to be 2 problems here :

1. When i put 'slash' it does not work and gives me not found errors. For example: `http://example.com/my-page/` now it will not work, but I put `http://example.com/my-page` then it will work fine, so i would like to both of them to work
2. Other problem is that `.html` pages are still opening. For example, if I open the page as `http://example.com/my-page.html` it is also working but I want it to convert to `http://example.com/my-page` automatically, I know I can use 301 redirects for this but that will not work as there are many of files here, so I have to use different 301 rules for different URLs.

Please Advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

URLRewrite 2.0 rule (insert this part inside `system.webServer` node) that replaces `.html` from url:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Hide .html ext">
            <match ignoreCase="true" url="^(.*)"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html" matchType="IsFile"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.html"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirecting .html ext" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*).html"/>
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).html"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: perfect.. saved lots of time

Comment: If you want to do this on a per-website basis you can just put this in web.config in the root of the virtual directory. I'll add a full reply too...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do this on a per-website basis using the local IIS server on Windows 10, install the URL Rewrite module and then put this in web.config in the root of your virtual directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <remove name="Redirecting .html ext" />
                <remove name="Hide .html ext" />
                <rule name="Hide .html ext" enabled="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html" matchType="IsFile" />
                    </conditions>
                    <serverVariables />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.html" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Redirecting .html ext" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*).html" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(.*)\.html$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <serverVariables />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Updating my response here with a better RegEx on the Redirect rule, so it only matches files ending with html and not (ahem) things like css files with html in the title...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is almost a year latter but I'll try. I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly but if I do I just use

```
    <system.webServer>
     <caching>
      <profiles>
       <remove extension=".php" />
       <remove extension=".html" />
       <add extension=".html" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="23:59:59" varyByQueryString="*" />
       <add extension=".php" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:00:30" varyByQueryString="*" />
             </profiles>
             </caching>
             <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
             <defaultDocument>
```

Then the rest of the closing statements that you are using.