# Remove .html extension from url using web.config only for urls that have .html and not home page

Tags: web, web-config, plesk

I have a Plesk account for my website hosting. I don't know anything about web.config files but I am trying to remove .HTML extensions from my URLs. I tried a solution (written later in the post), but it worked perfectly for all URLs but the home page. My home page shows the following error:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

(There is much more text in the error above, but I am trying to keep the question as brief as possible)

When I use [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com) it shows the error. When using [www.xyz.index.html](http://www.xyz.index.html), it works fine but the URL I see then becomes [www.xyz.index](http://www.xyz.index), which is unpleasant to look at. Please refer to this post below and help me with a solution if you can!

[Remove HTML extension with web config permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631493/remove-html-extension-with-web-config-permanently/35523747#35523747)

Code that is written as the best answer to the post above and also the one I am using:

```
<configuration>   
    <system.webServer>   
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Hide .html ext">
                    <match ignoreCase="true" url="^(.*)"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html" matchType="IsFile"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.html"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="Redirecting .html ext" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*).html"/>
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).html"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see what's wrong. It's either you forgot to put a /, or because it is a folder, or it is because you used many domains.

Comment: Hi! I am using just one domain name. Could you please explain to me the impact a / or a folder could have?

Comment: A / can change it. For example, it may have been <https://example.com/file-1.html/file-1.html>. Then you could have changed it to <https://example.com/file-1/file-1.html>. A solution is to do <https://example.com/file-1/file-1> (Rename the / property!)

Comment: If you are suggesting that I add a suffix to my homepage, then that isn't what I am looking for as a solution. I am aware that www.xyz.com/home will work but I don't want to do so. I want it to be www.xyz.com only and have other pages as www.xyz.com/abc

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)