# How to remove .html extension in .NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I'm serving a static HTML file in the wwwroot folder of the .NET 6 Web API

How can I remove or hide the .html extension? I tried implementing `mod_rewrite` rules in web.config file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631493/remove-html-extension-with-web-config-permanently) but it did not work. I renamed the `web.config` file to `app.config` as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46996480/how-to-read-web-config-file-in-net-core-app) but still did not work.

So basically, what I want to achieve is Uri rewrite from **https://localhost:5000/documentation.html** to **https://localhost:5000/documentation**

How is this done in Web API that is serving a static file?

Comment: why do you have .html files in web api project?

Comment: For the API documentation. I want to avoid having to host the static HTML file elsewhere when I can just use the `app.UseStaticFiles();` available in the web API project. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: so i think you don't have to emphasize webapi. you're just asking about asp.net mvc.

Comment: @Mate Thanks for sharing the link. I've tried out the answers but none work for me. I have tried the accepted answer before and it works but the only issue I have with it is that it requires me to add CSS and JavaScript inside the HTML file (internal or inline) and difficult to reference an image in the HTML `<img>` tag. I would love to add the CSS externally using the `<link>` element.

Comment: @Blogrammer  , using <link  href="~/css/your.css" .. > inside html works for me.  You need add your.css into wwwroot/css.  You could check from browser http://yoursite/css/your.css too

Comment: @Mate, yes it works for me too. You know when I first tried the controller approach, I was using `File(..)` instead of `Content(...)` or `Text(..)` Many thanks, you save my day.

Comment: This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48770473/12476466  solve my problem. Thanks to @Mate for sharing the link.