# iis url rewrite remove .html resulting in 404 Not Found

Tags: html, iis, url-rewriting

i want

`http://www.example.com/pages/service.html` ->  `http://www.example.com/pages/service`

but is resulting is 404 not Found

help me please ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url="^pages/(.*).html" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/pages/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If you go through some URL rewrite tutorials, you will see the actual approach is to reverse the URL change, by rewriting the ones without .html to .html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Hide .html ext">
        <match ignoreCase="true" url="^(.*)"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html" matchType="IsFile"/>
          </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.html"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirecting .html ext" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*).html"/>
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).html"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
     </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35523747/13336642